# Can a thermometer be used over the max indicated temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, liquid-state

So I have a thermometer in my film developing tank that is bonded to the inside of the tank and the max temperature is 25degree Celsius. 
Modern development chemicals must be heated to 38 degrees Celsius.
Can I still use my tank?
What will happen to the thermometer if I pour the 38 degrees Celsius liquid?

Comment: What is the thermometer made out of? Typical glass thermometers have a capillary filed with alcohol that expands when heated. Over heating these thermometers can lead to rupture of the glass. Regardless of the type, thermometers are rated for specific temperatures because they are calibrated to be accurate over those intervals

Comment: Did you check for warning labels on the instrument or available manuals?

Comment: Also if the thermometer has a max temperature of 25C how would you even know when the mixture hits 38C?

Comment: @Joe I think the question is whether it's safe to get the thermometer that hot since it is bonded it there and can't be removed, not whether it would be useful to measure temperature.

Comment: ah yeah ok I see that now

Comment: Thermometer is fixed on the inside of the tank, as I've said. The question is about how safe it is? 38 C I will measure outside with another thermometer.

Comment: You could look online for similar thermometers and check their safety ranges. I'm guessing damaging the thermometer is something you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Empty the tank of chemicals, fill with water at 40 or 42 deg C - if the thermometer breaks you have some cleaning to do, if not you are good to go...

We cannot tell how that thermometer will behave as you don’t provide an image of it, so guessing it will, or won’t, be ok is futile.

Test it and see.